# How to configure windows 10 not to open link in Edge?

Tags: windows-10

I use Google Chrome as my default browser in Windows 10, but when I click a link in external programs (for instance Skype, Teamcity) Microsoft Edge is launched and open the link instead of Google Chrome. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set your default browser:

1. in the Search bar type Default programs, and then tap or click Default Programs.
2. Tap or click Set your default programs.
3. Select Chrome from the list of programs.
4. Tap or click "Set this program as default", and then tap or click OK.
5. OR Tap or click "Choose defaults for this program" to choose other defaults

Comment: It's so weird that this worked, while manually picking Chrome from the list just left the option blank. I'm guessing this is a Windows 10 feature.

Comment: This didn't help me on Windows 10. I fixed it by uninstalling slack which I had installed from the Windows Store. I then downloaded the app from slack's website and installed it that way. Then links worked without further fiddling in Windows settings. Opened in Chrome on the first try.

Comment: The “Set default programs” option in Control Panel is now a link to the “Default apps” page in the new Settings, so this no longer works (Windows 10 version 21H1 build 19043.1052).

Answer (score 2):

For Me - The following worked

1. Create the GodMode folder.

   - Create a new folder and rename it to the following -> GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
2. Open the "GodMode" folder and find "Set Your Default Programs"
3. Open it and you will be able to select the program from the left panel and click "set this program as default"

Comment: It has been removed from god mode

Answer (score 1):

Go to Control Panel -> Default Programs -> Set your default programs.

Select Project Spartan/Google Chrome and check out the "Choose defaults for this program".

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Default Programs
2. Select Chrome
3. Then select Choose Defaults For This Program
4. Check Select All
5. Click Save

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get rid of the problem even in 21H1:
Settings > Default Apps > Set Defaults by App > [Choose your app, e.g., "Firefox"] > Manage > File Type and Protocol Associations > [Change to your app where desired and applicable]